# Intensity of an ultrasound beam?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, acoustics

I am working through [question 9.1](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=FwtX82skoEIC&pg=PA305&lpg=PA305&dq=%22consider%20a%20parallel%20ultrasound%20beam%22&source=bl&ots=ymHOLVJqqP&sig=cSacsLm2OWJdb9_LQsKHMg6vveY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiHiNnP__rOAhWlAcAKHejnAE8Q6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=%22consider%20a%20parallel%20ultrasound%20beam%22&f=false) (link to Google Books) of 'Fundamental Physics for Probing and Imaging' by Wade Allison. The question involves finding the varies quantities (such as pressure difference, particle velocity) etc. of a ultrasound wave of a given frequency $f$, intensity $I$, density $\rho$ and phase velocity $v_\phi$.

To do this question I have been using velocity potential $\phi=Ae^{i(kx-\omega t)}$. From which the pressure is given by:
$$p=\rho A i \omega e^{i(kx-\omega t)}$$
and velocity:
$$v=Aik e^{i(kx-\omega t)}$$
From this we can find the intensities as:
$$I=\left<pv\right>$$
$$=\frac{\rho_0}{2} A^2 \omega k$$
From which I can find $A$ and therefore the amplitude of the pressure and velocity. I have crossed checked this method with other sources and it seems to work ok. But in this case my values of $p$ and $v$ seem to be a factor of $\sqrt{2}$ out from what they should be (i.e compared to those [given in the book](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=FwtX82skoEIC&pg=PA330&lpg=PA330&dq=%22the%20pressure%20amplitude%20would%20reach%22&source=bl&ots=ymHOLVKplR&sig=nmNSASVODHvHeFpfJDpft6gaLRA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiSh4DmgvvOAhWEK8AKHV15B1IQ6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=%22the%20pressure%20amplitude%20would%20reach%22&f=false) (link to Google Books)). I was wondering if their was a reason for this discrepancy? Are there for example two different ways to define intensity or do reflected waves also need to be considered?

Comment: The link takes me to a page that I cannot view. Is it possible to reproduce the relevant equations?

Comment: @LasersMatter Try here https://www.researchgate.net/publication/234037777_Fundamental_Physics_for_Probing_and_Imaging page numbers are p330 and p360. Let me know if you still have problems I will try to give the relevant information.

Comment: Downloaded the book but the pdf only has 350 pages. The book only has 330 before the index. What section is it in?

Comment: @LasersMatter of the pdf pages p322 (end of section 9) and p346 (appendix c)   (I was meant to write p330 and p306  which are pages in the print copy sorry)

Comment: Does the $\sqrt{2}$ difference result from a different choice in how one normalizes a Fourier transform?  That is, one can choose to include the $\left( 2 \ \pi \right)^{-1}$ factor either in the forward or the backward or the square root in both.  It's a matter of choice so long as everything is consistent, I think.